# "bitter arguments and heated discussions" - meaning of "bitter"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I looked up *bitter* in the dictionary but this word is difficult to understand in the following context:

> Why the **bitter arguments** and **heated discussions** around Scotland's independence referendum might actually be a good thing.
>
> *(Source: [CBC Radio](https://www.facebook.com/radiocbc/posts/10152752043041913))*

What does *bitter* mean here?  Is there any difference between *bitter arguments* and *heated discussions*?

Comment: Please provide context— full sentences, at a minimum. Otherwise, no one can say definitively; for example, *bitter words* can refer either to words that are hurtful and thus cause bitterness to the listener, or to words which invoke bitterness in the speaker— or to words that mean *bitter*.

Comment: Let's reopen this question now that it has some context.

Comment: @snailboat — I should not think that the context of 'bitter arguments' and 'heated discussions' needed clarification, for they are set expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here *bitter* is used for **acrimonious** - 
:   bitterness, anger, rancor, resentment, ill feeling, ill will, bad blood, animosity, hostility, enmity, antagonism, waspishness, spleen, malice, spite, spitefulness, peevishness, venom, etc.
A "heated discussion" may not have the rancor, but it certainly has lots of passionate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

See the Thesaurus part of the Webster dictionary:

'*a bitter dispute* acrimonious, virulent, angry, rancorous, spiteful, vicious, vitriolic, savage, ferocious, hate-filled, venomous, poisonous, acrid, nasty, ill-natured. antonym amicable'.

Answer (score 0):

OALD has the entry for both! Furthermore, it's the same *context*

For the adjective *[bitter](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bitter_1)*

> (**of arguments**, disagreements, etc.) very serious and unpleasant, with a lot of anger and hatred involved

And, for the adjective *[heated](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/heated)*

> *(of a person or **discussion**) full of anger and excitement*

The sentence in concern uses *both the phrases* which triggers my mind and I can say that they just wanted to include everything i.e. anger, unpleasing and seriousness. Because had they used merely *heated discussion*, a chunk of readers might dismiss *unpleasing* as the meaning.

However, I see both quite similar. If something includes *anger*, it's quite unpleasing. Isn't it?

[Good to note that the adjective *bitter* can be used for anything that is *unpleasant*. *Bitter truth* is the commonest phrase to mean the truth which is *not-so-likeable*].